# docker-compose failed to build on windows 10

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to deploy my spring boot application with docker compose but get this error:

*Step 14/15 : COPY ${JAR_FILE} manager.jar
ERROR: Service 'manager' failed to build : When using COPY with more than one source file, the destination must be a directory and end with a /*

But if I do a docker build using the Dokerfile it works correctly. The question is, why fail with docker-compose up?.

*C:\Push\Workspace\manager>docker build --tag "docker-manager:latest" .
[+] Building 7.3s (8/8) FINISHED*

I have tried looking for examples but I am using windows 10

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} example.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "example.jar"]
```

The docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  oracle:
    image: container-registry-london.oracle.com/database/enterprise:12.2.0.1
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "1521:1521"
  manager:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "8181:8181"
    depends_on:
      - oracle
    links:
      - oracle
    restart: always
```

Comment: How many jar files is in your target folder ?

Comment: One jar (the jar from mi spring boot application

Comment: instead of *.jar try with full name and see what happens.

Comment: I get this error: `failed to build : COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder042396409/target/manager.jar: no such file or directory `

Comment: Can you show me the directory structure of your dockerfile and docker-compose file? Also please tell me how are you running the compose file ? Are you using docker-compose up at your directory with docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile?

Comment: The Dockerfile and docker.compose files are located in the root of the project. To execute the compose i'm doing this; open a cmd and got to the root of project and write docker-compose up". 
One thing, I have seen that when I do a maven install a jar is created with the name "test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar", but in the Dockerfile I am calling it "manager.jar" that may be the problem?

Comment: try using target/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar and use docker-compose up --build and see what happens.

Comment: Works! in the dockerfile i make this change `COPY ${JAR_FILE} ajpn-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`The problem was that when I did a maven install creates a .jar, and in the dockerfile another one and that is why the error message came out. Thanks @Shawrup

Comment: I am adding the solution as an answer for future reference. Please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing there might be mulitple jar files in your target folder.
In stead of using the *.jar , please use full name of the jar and then rebuild the dokcer compose file with --build flag.

```
ARG JAR_FILE=target/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Then build with

```
docker-compose up --build
```